# How to change configuration in distributed playframework application

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Currently using playframework 2.0.2 and in my application.conf i set the db connection info

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user=test
db.default.pass=test
```

But what I would like to know is when i put my application into production using "play clean update dist"
and then install it on site there is no application.conf. This means that I have to change the db connection before I distribute the code? is there a way to change the db connection in a config file after you have distributed it?

Answer (score 8):

When you use `play dist` the config files get packaged into a jar file in the zip.  You could create a `conf/prod.conf` file containing something like:

```
include "application.conf"

db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://foo.com:3306/mydb"
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user=foo
db.default.pass=bar
```

Then when you start the Play app tell it to use the `prod.conf` file by running:

```
start -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf
```

Comment: That would need a distribution package that contains the production password, wouldnt it? If i cannot include a prod password into an artefact, would it work to "start -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf -Ddb.default.pass=myBar"?

Comment: Yes, good clarification.  The config params can also be set using the `-D` command line args.  Or you can use `-Dconfig.file=/home/blah/prod.conf` to avoid putting the `prod.conf` file in the artifact.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid packaging the config file at all I would suggest that you create a prod.conf on the production servers and store in a folder other than folder you unzip the distributed files to. Then create a startup script like below (or a more sophisticated startup script that start your app as a service). By keeping the config file separate from you dist package you avoid the risk of accidentally overriding it when pushing out new changes.

```
#!/bin/bash
sh start -Dconfig.file=/path/to/prod.conf &
```